# ASP.NET TextBox filter

Tags: asp.net

is there a simple way to suppress certain keystrokes within a textbox? for example if i only want to allow numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built-in, you will need to [write some JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_onkeydown.asp) to capture and ignore the keys you want to disallow.

Or you can use this [FilteredTextBox](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx) control extender, from the [ASP .NET AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a <asp:CompareValidator>. E.g.

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="valNumbersOnly" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="controlYouWantToValidate"
    Operator="DataTypeCheck"
    Type="Integer"
    ErrorMessage="Please enter only numbers">*</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Or you could go even further and use a regular expression validator.

These solutions will work with and without javascript, so they will validate client side and server side. Not everyone has javascript turn on!

HTHs,
Charles