# How do i Make a textbox where i only can write some letters

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET TextBox filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637620/asp-net-textbox-filter)

If i have a textbox and i want to add a validation too it, how can i then add a validation, so i Only can write some letters, maybe T, K, or U or Empty !? so other letters like G,f,d,s Can't be used !?

Comment: You can use javascript for that, just validate the entered letter on 'keyup' or 'keypress' and see if the entered letter belongs to your list, else remove it.

Comment: @Thomas Use Regular Expression Validator.

Comment: That question has already been asked:


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637620/asp-net-textbox-filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a regular expression validator and supply a regular expression for what letters you want.

Such as letters only is:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationExpression="[aA-zZ]"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: Avitus, How do i add "empty" too this, so it allow empty field.

Answer (score 0):

also you have `KeyUp - KeyDown- KeyPress` events for text box which will be called when you type something in the textbox.There you can write your code on what ever characters you want to allow or restrict

```
public void OnKeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
MessageBox.Show(e.KeyCode.ToString(), "Your input");  //f(e.KeyChar == 4) you can loop like this


}
```

Or you can do with JavaScript or JQuery as well